# Story about school kids who go on a field trip to a fort

Tags: identification-request

Help me remember the name of this book from my youth.  I don't remember much about it but it was the story of a group of school kids who go on a field trip to a fort. I think something happens at the fort, like they are transported back in time and experience life in colonial (civil war maybe) time. They may have even taken part in resisting a siege. I know that isn't much to go on, but I'd love to find it and re-read it :)

Here are my responses to the Guide for this type of question:

**When did you read the story, and how old was it?**

I read the story when I was a kid, so I'd say at least 20 years ago, and I have no idea if it was an old book already at that time.

**Medium and appearance**

I do not remember what the cover looked like, but I remember it was a book, and not a magazine or a story from a textbook or anything like that.  My feeling was that it was a typical length for a YA book, probably no more that 200 pages.

**What language did you read it in, and was it translated?**

English, and I doubt if it was translated but you never know!

**Where did you read this story?**

It is very likely that I read this story either in the public library, or I checked it out from the library.  I did a lot of "summer reading" events when I was a kid and I took crap-tons of books out of the library in those days.

Comment: Welcome to Literature! We'd like to help you find this book, but we're going to need a bit more information to do so. We have a [guide](https://literature.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info) for questions asking for story identification - could you take a look at it and add some details to your question?

Comment: Thanks for editing! :-) One more question: "*life in colonial (civil war maybe) time*" - which former colony was this book set in? USA?

Comment: Yes, if I recall correctly, the fort the visited was either a US civil war fort, or a colonial era fort.

Comment: There's  "The War at Fort Maggie" by Raymond Bradbury, but it seems to be about made up Canadian fort and no time travel: https://www.umanitoba.ca/cm/cmarchive/vol10no4/warfortmaggie.html